# WordPress: Pass variable on page change

Tags: wordpress, variables, cookies, global-variables

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to do the following.

1. I have a page which shows a selection of projects. There are 2 possible views: a list and a map.
2. When the user clicks on "map", the list disappears and the map appears. This is all done in JavaScript, so there is not page reload.
3. The user can filter projects by category. When he changes the category, the page reloads. I have fiddled with doing it in JavaScript (so there wouldn't be any reload), but the reload is important since when want different pages with different URLs for each catagory.
4. When the user changes the category (hence, the page reloads), I want to be able to retrieve the previous display state selected, list or map.

Which would be to most efficient way to go? How should I store the value so I can retrieve it on the next page load? Global var, cookie?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i uess your best option would be to use ajax to load the content based on users selection and toggle the map and list views according without reloading the page. This will allow you to retain all selected values.